# The value of $\cos 0^\circ.\cos 1^\circ.\cos 2^\circ.....\cos 170^\circ$ is..

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The value of $\cos 0^\circ.\cos 1^\circ.\cos 2^\circ.....\cos 170^\circ$ is..

My Attempt:

Let,
$$x= \cos 0^\circ.\cos 1^\circ.\cos 2^\circ.....\cos 170^\circ$$
$$x=1. \cos 1^\circ.\cos 2^\circ.....\cos 170^\circ$$

How do I calculate further?

Comment: Cosine of ninety degree is zero.

Comment: $\cos 88^\circ, \cos 89^\circ,\ldots$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\cos 0^\circ.\cos 1^\circ.\cos 2^\circ\cdots\cos 170^\circ$

=$\cos 0^\circ.\cos 1^\circ.\cos 2^\circ\cdots \cos 88^\circ\cdot\cos89^\circ\cdot(\cos90^\circ) \cdots \cos 170^\circ$

=$\cos 0^\circ.\cos 1^\circ.\cos 2^\circ...(0)..\cos 170^\circ$

=0

Answer (score 1):

Hint: cos(90°) =0 
If you see ..since it's all product 0* anything is 0.